# View with UIModalPresentationFormSheet is blurred

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I'm currently making ipad application.

I have create an uiviewcontroller which is appear with modal presentation.

When I open this view, it is blurred and I don't know why...

Look, the left is clear, the right is blur :

[image]

My code :

```
- (IBAction)showView:(id)sender {
    Myviewcontroller *myviewcontroller = [[Myviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Myviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
 myviewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
 myviewcontroller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:myviewcontroller animated:YES];
    myviewcontroller.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 635, 400);
myviewcontroller.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the width of `635` leads to problems when centering the view:

```
(1024-635) / 2 = 194,5
(768-635) / 2 = 66,5
```

Core Graphics handles co-ordinates as floats, not integers, so position views with sub-pixel accuracy is possible and will produce this anti-alias like blur-effect. This is possible because view coordinates are specified with CGRect, which uses CGPoint, where x and y are floats.

Try a width of `636` pixels instead and you should be fine :)